# Fine tuning Search API with Solr

Tags: search

After figuring out that `tokenizer` was breaking up a search phrases into individual keywords and turning that off in the UI, searching for a phrase actually brought the expected page onto the first page of search results. This was a huge improvement. However, a page that does not have the exact phrase, but does have more mentions of keywords in the phrase, will actually rank higher in the results. Via the Search API interface, using Type-specific boosting, you can boost a given bundle, but how does one boost exact phrase to have more weight than multiple instances of keywords?

Note that Solr is provided by the hosting provider, who also provides a pre-configured schema.xml file. The file is well commented but the research I've done thus far suggests that I would likely do more damage than good if I modify it.

All guidance appreciated at this point as I have experimented with this extensively and I think I've hit the limit of self discovery. I don't want to resort to hidden text to fix local search as I'm concerned with getting dinged for that by the major search engines.